# c++ template specialization-specific declaration

Tags: c++, templates

Basically, what i'm trying to do is build a Vector template, with two arguments: dimensions, and variable type.

```
template <typename Type, unsigned ElementCount>
class TVector
    {
    private:
    public:
        union
            {
            struct
                {
                Type X, Y, Z, W;
                };
            struct
                {
                Type Red, Green, Blue, Alpha;
                };
            Type Values[ElementCount];
            };
    }
```

It all works ok, but as you may have noticed, this is only for 4-element vectors, since only the Values variable is dependent on ElementCount. ElementCount=1 declares only X and Red, 2 declares Y and Green, and so on...
So, what i wanted was to have the other variables being declared also depending on the ElementCount value.

Is it at all possible? I don't think so, but wanted to make sure, anyway.

I was thinking of declaring that whole union separately and passing it along as a template parameter, but that's ugly as hell....

EDIT:
Dammit. Now i remembered something... What about the constructor-by-value?

The argument count is dependent of the template parameter ElementCount... How to do this?

Comment: I think you need to better clarify what purpose this template is serving. For instance why don't you want to just pass around 4 values or an array of values?

Comment: I basically want to create a bunch of 2, 3 or 4D vectors. I already have all the functions written to use them ( operators, length, normalizing, etc etc ) using the ElementCount, so all works. But i'd really like to maintain the X Y Z W variables, for readability. Of course, a 3D vector does not have a W component, hence this question...

Comment: But the total number of elements, is it bound by a fixed number (4?) or can it be larger than that?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas. Well, it's not hardcoded bound. But it should never be higher than 4. I can't imagine declaring a 5D vector, or something...

Comment: Please don't indent your braces to the same level as their inner block. It's just ugly and unhelpful.

Comment: @Griwes. Indentation styles are basically religion. Each developer has their own, and defends it as being the best. And i don't discuss religion.. In these answers alone, i can identify 3 different styles. Do you want to tell everyone that their style is wrong? As for ugly and unhelpful, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style

Comment: I know that many people have their own styles, and most of them I can accept, but the one you used is plainly harmful.

Comment: What's wrong with just the array of values? Why the union (it's `private`, so only matters for the internals of your class)?

Comment: It's not private. There's a public: statement on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with partial specialization. Something like

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct S
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            T X, Y, Z, W;
        };

        struct
        {
            T Red, Green, Blue, Alpha;
        };

        T Values[N];
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct S<T, 1>
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            T X;
        };

        struct
        {
            T Red;
        };

        T Values[1];
    };
};

int main()
{
    using S1 = S<char, 1>;
    using S5 = S<char, 5>;

    std::cout << "sizeof(S1) = " << sizeof(S1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(S5) = " << sizeof(S5) << '\n';
}
```

It should print

```
sizeof(S1) = 1
sizeof(S5) = 5
```

Also, doing e.g.

```
S1 s1;
s1.Y = 0;
```

should give you an error that the structure have no member `Y`.

Yes it's a lot more to write (or copy-paste) but it should solve your problem.

Comment: You could inherit from the previous N's version of the union?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass in the whole union -- just the struct and the type of the fields.  I've also added a syntactic sugar in operator-> so you don't have to reference the .Names part if you don't wish.

```
#include <iostream>

struct PointStruct {
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Z;
};

struct ColorStruct {
    int Red;
    int Green;
    int Blue;
    int Alpha;
};


template <typename Type, typename Struct>
class TVector
{
public:
    const static int LEN = sizeof(Struct) / sizeof(Type);
    union
        {
            Struct Names;
            Type Values[LEN];
        };
    Struct* operator->() { return &Names; }
    const Struct* operator->() const { return &Names; }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    TVector < int, PointStruct > points;
    points.Names.X = 55;
    points.Names.Y = -67;
    points.Names.Z = 42;
    for (int x = 0; x < points.LEN; ++x) {
        std::cout << "points[" << x << "]: " << points.Values[x] << std::endl;
    }
    points.Values[1] = 135;
    std::cout << "points->Y: " << points->Y << std::endl;
    TVector < int, ColorStruct > colors;
    colors.Names.Red = 1;
    colors.Names.Green = 2;
    colors.Names.Blue = 3;
    colors.Names.Alpha = 4;
    for (int x = 0; x < colors.LEN; ++x) {
        std::cout << "colors[" << x << "]: " << colors.Values[x] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With g++ 4.3 I get

```
points[0]: 55
points[1]: -67
points[2]: 42
points->Y: 135
colors[0]: 1
colors[1]: 2
colors[2]: 3
colors[3]: 4
```

Comment: I liked this way. This way i can even change from RGBA to XYZW, by just changing the Names struct. Now i just have to find a way to make it unnamed, so i can do Point.X, instead of Point.Names.X

Comment: I was looking for the same thing.  The nearest I could come is to implement operator-> to return a Struct*.  Then at least you could reference points->Y or colors->Red.  Unfortunately you'll still have to change your calling code, so not certain if that will help you.  Did you end up using partial specialization instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid specialization at this level, rather do it inside the union itself:

```
template <typename T> struct X   { T x; };
template <typename T> struct XY  { T x, y; };
...

template <typename T, int Count>
struct CountToXYZWType {};
template <typename T> struct CountToXYZWType<T,1> { typedef X<T>  type; };
template <typename T> struct CountToXYZWType<T,2> { typedef XY<T> type; };
...

template <typename T, int Count>
struct TVector {
   union {
      typename CountToXYZWType<Count>::type;
      // similarly CountToColorType<Count> ...
      T values[Count];
   }
...
```

};

Comment: That specialization does not compile for me. It complains about a missing template argument ( should be 2, is only 1 ).

Comment: @RhiakathFlanders: That was a typo in the answer. The type argument was missing from the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, a big thank you for everyone, for all the ideas. I finally managed to do what i wanted, using a mix of all you suggested.

second, let me explain, then. I wanted to rewrite my math library. I basically had a class for 2d, 3d and 4d vectors each. It was stupid, since most of the code is the same, so i decided to try to refactor using templates.

I also had a small class named RGB and another called RGBA for obvious reasons :).

And as such, i embarked on this adventure with templates ( i'm not a big fan, but mainly because i can't understand them. they're certainly very useful ).

So, after several failed tries, I changed approach. The final result is a mix of all the above and the kitchen sync. A small taste, including member functions ( i had some trouble with those ), the union with the named member variables is available here: http://goo.gl/4Zlt20

Now, for one final question, if i may...

It all works the way i want it, but for some reason, i can't get rid of that "this->" on the inline functions. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks.